# IIS issues handling URL/Querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, iis, query-string

I have a page that opens in a new tab when a link is clicked.  Data is loaded into the page based on querystring values.  I have tested this page in IE, Firefox and Chrome on my local machine and it loads perfectly. When I try it on the live server, the page loads with no errors, however none of the data is loaded and I have a page with a bunch of blank fields displaying.  Like I said, I've tried it with multiple browsers on my local machine, and I've pointed my local code to the live database and it worked fine.  The only thing I can think of is that perhaps it's an issue with the way IIS is handling the URL and/or Querystring values.  Is there any settings in IIS that would prevent the data from loading, or does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

How do you think IIS is preventing your data to load? And arr you not using any kind of logging or exception handling? That way you will be able to get something about what might be wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's IIS, I really don't know what it is.  I have exception handling, but I am not getting any exceptions or even javascript errors.  the only difference that I can think of between my local machine and the server is maybe an IIS setting, but I'm not sure

Comment: Did you check for any errors/warning in Windows event logs?

Answer (score 0):

fixed, this was caused by an incorrect reference in our page, nothing to do with IIS